# How to fix 'Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid using react-native-svg-charts with Expo

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I'm trying to add a gradient to my area chart using react-native-svg-charts from this example: https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts-examples/blob/master/storybook/stories/area-chart/with-gradient.js.

The code compiles but I get the following error at runtime:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRKAQ.jpg (sorry I don't have enough) reputation to post an image yet)

I'm using Expo on my Android phone. I'm fairly new to programming, so I'm not sure what to even try.

```
import * as shape from 'd3-shape'
import { View } from 'native-base';
import * as React from 'react';
import { AreaChart, Defs, LinearGradient, Path, Stop } from 'react-native-svg-charts'
// import styles from './styles';

class DashboardChart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = [ 50, 10, 40, 95, 14, 24, 85, 91, 35, 53, 53, 24, 50, 20, 80 ]

        const ChartLine = ({line}) => (
            <Path
                key={'line'}
                d={line}
                stroke={'rgb(134, 65, 244)'}
                fill={'none'}
            />
        )

        const Gradient = ({ index }) => (
          <Defs key={index}>
              <LinearGradient id={'gradient'} x1={'0%'} y={'0%'} x2={'0%'} y2={'100%'}>
                  <Stop offset={'0%'} stopColor="blue" stopOpacity={1}/>
                  <Stop offset={'100%'} stopColor="white" stopOpacity={1}/>
              </LinearGradient>
          </Defs>
      )

    return (
          <View>
            <AreaChart
                style={{ height: 200 }}
                data={data}
                contentInset={{ top: 40, bottom: 10 }}
                curve={shape.curveNatural}
                svg={{
                  fill: 'url(#gradient)'
                }}
            >
                {/* <Grid/> */}
                <Gradient/>
                <ChartLine/>
            </AreaChart>
          </View>
    );
  }

}

export default DashboardChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example that you linked to the `Defs`, `LinearGradient`, and `Stop` components were imported from `react-native-svg`. So those components may be `undefined` in the `react-native-svg-charts` library, which would explain the error you are seeing.

Try fixing your imports to this (installing `react-native-svg` if you haven't already):

```
import { AreaChart } from 'react-native-svg-charts'
import { Defs, LinearGradient, Path, Stop } from 'react-native-svg'
```